# Можно ли продавать готовый продукт написанный на языке Go?

Tags: golang, лицензирование

Позволяет ли лицензия Go продавать готовый продукт, написанный на нем? Что-то не могу с этим вопросом разобраться? Или готовый продукт тоже должен быть Open Source?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/LICENSE - вот лицензия, и как видите на commercial use стоит галочка, значит никаких проблем

Comment: @Buka это только про сам компилятор, и программ, скомпилированных с помощью него, не касается, не?

Comment: прочитайте текст ниже, использование продукта в любой форме распространяется с условиями, среди которых нет ограничения на коммерческое использование

Comment: ИМХО ограничения могут быть только на использование конкретного компилятора, но никак не на язык. Еще 100500 лет назад было постановление, что система команд не подлежит лицензированию Тогда судились Интел и АМД. Интел хотели запретить АМД делать процессоры с такой же системой команд, как у х86. Но суд отверг такие претензии.

Answer (score 1):

Можно если все используемые пакеты не имеют этого ограничения

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Лицензия BSD не запрещает.